# How to apply x and y coridinates to jbuttons in a grid layout

Tags: java

I have this arraylist

```
ArrayList<JButton> b;
int limit = 16;
for(int i = 0; i< limit; i++){
    gameBoard.add(new JButton("Counter"));
}
```

Need to make another method where it loops through x, y coordinates to get the buttons in a grid layout. How can I do this.

Answer (score 0):

When talking about *Swing* you can simply add the Buttons within a simple loop because the constructor of `GridLayout` accepts a `0` as one of the parameters:

```
 // limit/3 columns and as many rows as needed -> 3 or 4
 JPanel panelWithGrid = new JPanel( new GridLayout(0,limit/3)); 
 for(int i = 0; i< limit; i++){
       JButton b =new JButton("Counter");
       gameBoard.add(b) ;
       panelWithGrid.add(b) ;
    }
```